# Keyboard Layouts missing in Keyboard Layout --Precise upgrade

Tags: keyboard-layout, settings

This is from a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/console-setup/+bug/881222) I reported that never got a response. That was a 11.10 upgrade and now with a Precise upgrade, the issue continues with the Precise upgrade.

---

### Symptom

I can't add alternative keyboard layouts.

### Steps to reproduce

1. Go to Keyboard Layout
2. Press the + button
3. Nothing at all appears. That is, no selections to choose from.

Realize the + button is faded, despite that the other buttons (- and others) light up.

### Expected results

Alternative keyboard layouts should appear to choose from.

---

This is what I've done since then without results that stick.

Thinking that the problem is linked to the fact that I uninstalled other-than-English language support with BleachBit, I did the following:

- reinstalled language-selector-gnome
- reinstalled language-pack-en-base

I went back to Keyboard Layout and the + button is still faded.

I even went so far as to add Spanish locale to see if I could add another layout, but this didn't make a difference. I can't add any layouts to the ones I already have installed (US alternative, US International, English Mac, and the International alt/Gr version).

I tried the following:

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales
update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Although it did seem to update my locale settings, when I went back to Keyboard Layout, the + button was still faded.

I haven't tried `dpkg-reconfigure localeconfig` because this is not installed and apparently `xkeyboard-config` is an EOL.

`xkb-data` looks promising from the description in the Software Center:

> "This package contains configuration data used by the X Keyboard Extension (XKB), which allows selection of keyboard layouts when using a graphical interface."

A quick wajig reinstall `xkb-data` proved my hopes wrong.

It seems the only thing that temporarily allowed me to install more layouts was `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`. I selected the colemak layout to see if it took. I ran it but by the time I rebooted, the change didn't stick.

I just reinstalled `iso-codes`, and for a few minutes I saw that the keyboard applet showed  colemak I had installed previously with. I relogged back in and it was gone, but colemak shows in `cat /etc/default/keyboard` but not in Xorg. A quick <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> showed me that it did take, but only in console.

```
XKBMODEL="pc104"
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT="colemak"
XKBOPTIONS="terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
```

Somehow I don't think `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` was meant to (only?) change the console layout.

I'm just reading `/etc/default/keyboard` and it says the following:

```
# If you change any of the following variables and X is configured to
# use this file, then the changes will become visible to X only if udev
# is restarted.  You may need to reboot the system.
```

I can assume that X is listening, at least until I reboot, when changes are thrown away. So, I assume there is a conflict between more than one file or sets of files as to which layouts take predominance.

Any ideas anyone? This one has me stumped.

Oh, and I wonder if this Keyboard input method system menu selection under Language Support has anything to do with this. I would assume no.

#### Aside

Another solution, if I weren't already using my own `.Xmodmap` file would be to do something like `sudo xmodmap /usr/share/xmodmap/xmodmap.uk`.

Comment: Can't help wondering why the system bumps an old precise question.

Answer (score 1):

The Keyboard Layout window inexplicably won't allow you to choose more than 4 layouts. However, you can fire up `gconf-editor` and navigate to `/desktop/gnome/peripherals/kbd/layouts` and manually add as many layouts as you like.

I don't understand the arbitrary limit in the GUI, though.

Comment: Yeah, I fount out about the 4 layout limit some hours ago. I didn't know about /desktop/gnome/peripherals/kbd/layouts in gconf-editor, though. I've been using dconf so I'll dig through that for the same preference.

Comment: Apparently, in dconf that's /org/gnome/libgnomekbd/keyboard/layouts

Comment: as in ['us\tintl', 'us\talt-intl', 'us\taltgr-intl']

Comment: How do you come up with the strings to put there?

Comment: The 4-layout limit is hardcoded in XKB, unfortunately.  one workaround is to use a script to divide your layouts into groups of 4 or less.  the script would use `setxkbmap` or `gsettings` to set the next group of layouts.  (disable `gnome-settings-daemon`'s keyboard plugin if using `setxkbmap` for this).