# I can't add a new keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard-layout

I can't add any new layout to my keyboard, the button is deactivated.

an error message raised to me to include the output of those 4 commands in the error report.

```
moemen@moemen:~$ xprop -root | grep XKB
_XKB_RULES_NAMES_BACKUP(STRING) = "evdev", "pc105", "us", "", ""
_XKB_RULES_NAMES(STRING) = "evdev", "pc105", "us", "", "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
moemen@moemen:~$ gsettings get org.gnome.libgnomekbd.keyboard model
''
moemen@moemen:~$ gsettings get org.gnome.libgnomekbd.keyboard layouts
@as []
moemen@moemen:~$ gsettings get org.gnome.libgnomekbd.keyboard options
@as []
```

Comment: Does [this help](http://askubuntu.com/a/123586/12864)? If yes, this may be a duplicate.

Comment: It's a different error, the solution mentioned there: the layout is empty, and has notification `This key has no schema` .

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved!

It was just a permission issue. So, I changed the ownership of the keyboard configuration, and it works well now :)